# python equivalent of java OutputStream?

Tags: python, abstraction

Is there a Python equivalent / pseudo-equivalent to java's [OutputStream](http://download.oracle.com/javase/1.4.2/docs/api/java/io/OutputStream.html) or [PrintWriter](http://download.oracle.com/javase/1.4.2/docs/api/java/io/PrintWriter.html)?

I want to be able to have a handle that represents either a stream like stdout/sterr, or a file, or something else (a pipe or a socket or a dummy sink) and abstract away what kind of thing it is, so I can just send output to it.

How can I do this?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

"Abstracting away what type it is" happens automatically in Python - it's called 'duck typing'. Just pass any file-like object to the function, and have it use the interface of file-like objects.

FWIW, the standard input/output/error streams are represented by `stdin`, `stdout` and `stderr` in the `sys` module. To get file-like objects that read and write strings, use the `StringIO` module.

Answer (score 3):

Take a look at the [io](http://docs.python.org/library/io.html) and [StringIO](http://docs.python.org/library/stringio.html) modules.

Answer (score 1):

you just need an object that implements the methods that files, pipes, streams, etc... also implement. for instance, i use this class sometimes when i want to detach my python program and i want to redirect sys.stderr/sys.stdout:

```
class Log(object):
    """used for logging for background process"""
    def __init__(self, f):
            self.f = f
    def write(self, s):
            self.f.write(s)
            self.f.flush()
sys.stdout = sys.stderr = Log(open('/tmp/daemonlog', 'a+'))
```