# Python 2.7: print doesn't speak unicode to the io module?

Tags: python, unicode, io

```
import sys, codecs, io

codecsout = codecs.getwriter('utf8')(sys.stdout)
ioout = io.open(sys.stdout.fileno(), mode='w', encoding='utf8')
print >> sys.stdout, 1
print >> codecsout, 2
print >> ioout, 3
```

Fails with:

```
1
2
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "print.py", line 7, in <module>
    print >> ioout, 3
TypeError: must be unicode, not str
```

It fails with `print(3, file=ioout)` from the `__future__` as well.

Does `print` not know how to talk to the `io` module?

Comment: Almost exact duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4512982/python-typeerror-cant-write-str-to-text-stream

Answer (score 2):

Evidently it doesn't. Even if you give it an explicit Unicode string, it doesn't work.

```
>>> print >> ioout, u'3'
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
TypeError: must be unicode, not str
```

I'm guessing the problem is in the newline that is automatically appended to the end. The print function from the future doesn't appear to have the same problem:

```
>>> from __future__ import print_function
>>> print(unicode(3), file=ioout)
3
```

Answer (score 0):

The `print` statement implicitly calls `__str__` on each thing it prints. `sys.stdout` is a byte-stream, so sending it a `str` is fine. `codecs.getwriter` is an old Python API so I'm guessing it just implicitly converts `str` to `unicode` as Python 2.x traditionally does. However, the new `io` module is strict about converting `str` to `unicode` as Python 3.x is, which is why it complains.

So, if you want to send unicode data to a stream, use the `.write()` method instead of `print`:

```
>>> sys.stdout.write(u'1\n')
1
>>> codecsout.write(u'1\n')
1
>>> sys.stdout.write(u'1\n')
1
```