# Redirect stdout to a file with unicode encoding while keeping windows eol in python 2

Tags: python, python-2.7, unicode, io, eol

I hit a wall here. I need to redirect all output to a file but I need this file to be encoded in utf-8. Problem is that when using [`codecs.open`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/codecs.html#codecs.open):

```
# errLog = io.open(os.path.join(os.getcwdu(),u'BashBugDump.log'), 'w',
#                  encoding='utf-8')
errLog = codecs.open(os.path.join(os.getcwdu(), u'BashBugDump.log'),
                     'w', encoding='utf-8')
sys.stdout = errLog
sys.stderr = errLog
```

codecs opens the file in binary mode resulting in `\n` line terminators. I tried using `io.open` but this does not play with the print statement used all over the codebase (see [Python 2.7: print doesn't speak unicode to the io module?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/14205548/281545) or [python: TypeError: can't write str to text stream](https://stackoverflow.com/q/4512982/281545))

I am not the only one having this issue for instance see [here](https://github.com/nvaccess/nvda/issues/732) but the [solution they adopted](https://github.com/nvaccess/nvda/commit/2d46a35ded41983a9ba1e3e14f2ed252e08ff77a) is specific to the logging module we do not use.

See also this won't fix bug in python: https://bugs.python.org/issue2131

So what's the one right way for doing this in python2 ?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

### Option 1

Redirection is a shell operation.  You don't have to change the Python code at all, but you do have to tell Python what encoding to use if redirected.  That is done with an environment variable.  The following code redirects both stdout and stderr to a UTF-8-encoded file:

#### test.bat

```
set PYTHONIOENCODING=utf8
python test.py >out.txt 2>&1
```

#### test.py

```
#coding:utf8
import sys
print u"我不喜欢你女朋友！"
print >>sys.stderr, u"你需要一个新的。"
```

#### out.txt (encoded in UTF-8)

```
我不喜欢你女朋友！
你需要一个新的。
```

#### Hex dump of out.txt

```
0000: E6 88 91 E4 B8 8D E5 96 9C E6 AC A2 E4 BD A0 E5
0010: A5 B3 E6 9C 8B E5 8F 8B EF BC 81 0D 0A E4 BD A0 
0020: E9 9C 80 E8 A6 81 E4 B8 80 E4 B8 AA E6 96 B0 E7
0030: 9A 84 E3 80 82 0D 0A
```

Note: You *do* need to print Unicode strings for this to work.  Print byte strings and you get the bytes you print.

### Option 2

`codecs.open` may force binary mode, but `codecs.getwriter` doesn't.  Give it a  file opened in text mode:

```
#coding:utf8
import sys
import codecs
sys.stdout = sys.stderr = codecs.getwriter('utf8')(open('out.txt','w'))
print u"我不喜欢你女朋友！"
print >>sys.stderr, u"你需要一个新的。"
```

(same output and hexdump as above)

Comment: Option 2 may very well be it - will try that ASAP. option 1 however did not work - see: https://github.com/wrye-bash/wrye-bash/commit/01d537e99540cae6c3e3e034b86450cad421d66a for my full list of attempts - in short we start the program from a bat file - even if I add  `set PYTHONIOENCODING=utf8` then when we redirect the stdout to a file _inside the application_  the encoding ends up being None

Comment: Exactly what I was looking for, I knew they'd be one Right Way - thanks :) : Note to self: https://wiki.python.org/moin/StreamWriter

Comment: @Mr_and_Mrs_D Glad it worked.  I'm not sure what didn't work for you about option 1.  In my testing after your comment, stdout has no encoding because the StreamWriter object doesn't set it, but the output written to the file is UTF-8.

Comment: Thanks Mark - what didn't work for me with option 1 is that we do not redirect the stdout on launching the script from the bat file but from inside the program - redirecting from inside the program does not take into account the PYTHONIOENCODING. Your second option was exactly what I needed (a pure std, no hacks, passing a text file to an encoded stream - what I missed was the Stream API, at some point one has to just ask I guess)

Answer (score 1):

It appears that the Python 2 version of `io` doesn't play well with the `print` statement, but it will work if you use the `print` function.

Demo:

```
from __future__ import print_function
import sys
import io

errLog = io.open('test.log', mode='wt', buffering=1, encoding='utf-8', newline='\r\n')
sys.stdout = errLog

print(u'This is a ™ test')
print(u'Another © line')
```

**contents of 'test.log'**

```
This is a ™ test
Another © line
```

**hexdump of 'test.log'**

```
00000000  54 68 69 73 20 69 73 20  61 20 e2 84 a2 20 74 65  |This is a ... te|
00000010  73 74 0d 0a 41 6e 6f 74  68 65 72 20 c2 a9 20 6c  |st..Another .. l|
00000020  69 6e 65 0d 0a                                    |ine..|
00000025
```

I ran this code on Python 2.6 on Linux, YMMV.

---

If you don't want to use the `print` function, you can implement your own file-like encoding class.

```
import sys

class Encoder(object):
    def __init__(self, fname):
        self.file = open(fname, 'wb')

    def write(self, s):
        self.file.write(s.replace('\n', '\r\n').encode('utf-8'))

errlog = Encoder('test.log')
sys.stdout = errlog
sys.stderr = errlog

print 'hello\nthere'
print >>sys.stderr, u'This is a ™ test'
print u'Another © line'
print >>sys.stderr, 1, 2, 3, 4
print 5, 6, 7, 8
```

**contents of 'test.log'**

```
hello
there
This is a ™ test
Another © line
1 2 3 4
5 6 7 8
```

**hexdump of 'test.log'**

```
00000000  68 65 6c 6c 6f 0d 0a 74  68 65 72 65 0d 0a 54 68  |hello..there..Th|
00000010  69 73 20 69 73 20 61 20  e2 84 a2 20 74 65 73 74  |is is a ... test|
00000020  0d 0a 41 6e 6f 74 68 65  72 20 c2 a9 20 6c 69 6e  |..Another .. lin|
00000030  65 0d 0a 31 20 32 20 33  20 34 0d 0a 35 20 36 20  |e..1 2 3 4..5 6 |
00000040  37 20 38 0d 0a                                    |7 8..|
00000045
```

Please bear in mind that this is just a quick demo. You may want a more sophisticated way to handle newlines, eg you probably don't want to replace `\n` if it's already preceded by `\r`. OTOH, with normal Python text handling that shouldn't be an issue...

---

Here's yet another version which combines the 2 previous strategies. I don't know if it's any faster than the second version.

```
import sys
import io

class Encoder(object):
    def __init__(self, fname):
        self.file = io.open(fname, mode='wt', encoding='utf-8', newline='\r\n')

    def write(self, s):
        self.file.write(unicode(s))

errlog = Encoder('test.log')
sys.stdout = errlog
sys.stderr = errlog

print 'hello\nthere'
print >>sys.stderr, u'This is a ™ test'
print u'Another © line'
print >>sys.stderr, 1, 2, 3, 4
print 5, 6, 7, 8
```

This produces the same output as the previous version.

Comment: It does as stated in the linked questions - point is I don't want to change the rest of the code

Comment: @Mr_and_Mrs_D Fair enough. Please see my alternate solution. BTW, you should seriously consider migrating your code to Python 3 because Python 2 won't be supported after 2020.

Comment: I would like to avoid replacing by hand `\n` and instead rely on python's automatic handling of text files eol while at the same time passing an encoded stream in - I would hope that there is some stream API that I am not familiar with. I could have hacked it like this but my question is really if this can be done with the std (get write stream ?). See the linked commit in github for using logging Stream classes. Re: python3, sure but this is a legacy application which i have been refactoring for 2 years now - once refactoring is over hopefully switching to python 3 would be easy.

Comment: For the record, updating a codebase to Python 3 `print` functions is not too hard; the `2to3` converter that ships with Python can be told to only perform the `print` fix, then you just add the `__future__` import to files that use `print`. So you're only manually changing the top line of a few files, not changing each and every use of `print` by hand.

Comment: @ShadowRanger: thanks I know, it's just "one thing at a time". Plus I am interested to see a solution to this anyway, in the lines of: https://github.com/nvaccess/nvda/commit/2d46a35ded41983a9ba1e3e14f2ed252e08ff77a. As you can see they still open the file in text mode just passing a SteamWriter encoded in utf8 - but they use the logging module (in my TODOs too but needs a lot of thought this one)

Comment: @Mr_and_Mrs_D FWIW, I've added another version of the `Encoder` class.

Comment: Well - see @marc's answer - the Encoder you define is pretty much the StreamWriter as discussed here: https://wiki.python.org/moin/StreamWriter