# Python equivalent of java ObjectOutputStream and ObjectInputStream?

Tags: java, python, equivalent

In java I can transfer objects between server and client by using [Object Output Stream](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/io/ObjectOutputStream.html) and [Object Input Stream](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/io/ObjectInputStream.html). Is there anything equivalent in python?

**Related:**

- [python equivalent of java OutputStream?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4512733/python-equivalent-of-java-outputstream)

Comment: Python might prefer to use JSOn or XML instead of having its own binary format.

Comment: Actually I'm trying to transfer object between two processes in same machines. These objects aren't purely data objects. I'm not sure if it'll work.

Comment: Reminds me of this statement 'XML is not the answer. It is not even the question. To paraphrase Jamie Zawinski on regular expressions, "Some people, when confronted with a problem, think "I know, I'll use XML." Now they have two problems."' http://dirtsimple.org/2004/12/python-is-not-java.html

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The pickle module in Python provides object serialization and deserialization functionality.  http://docs.python.org/library/pickle.html

It's not particularly secure, so you should always validate the incoming data, but it should support your needs.

Answer (score 3):

The multiprocessing module has the Pipe() function that handles serializing and passing objects between processes.
http://docs.python.org/library/multiprocessing.html#multiprocessing.Pipe

example (pipes work within the same process too)

```
import multiprocessing

class ObjectToSend:
    def __init__(self,data):
        self.data = data

obj = ObjectToSend(['some data'])

#create 2 read/write ends to a pipe
a, b = multiprocessing.Pipe()
#serialize and send obj across the pipe using send method
a.send(obj) 
#deserialize object at other end of the pipe using recv method
print(b.recv().data)
```